# Backbone View won't render on first page load

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have this strange issue where a view doesn't show up when I go to the page. However, if I refresh the page, it'll appear.

In my router, I tried to render 2 views like so:

```
tags: function(tags) {
        self = this;
        self.multipleTags = tags.split('/');
        self.tagsArray = $.grep(self.multipleTags, function(item,index) {
            return (item != '');
        });
        var browseHeader = new BrowseHeader;
        var content = new tagsView({query:self.tagsArray});
    },
```

I'm having trouble with my BrowseHeader though but the tagsView works fine. **I did try removing my tagsView** to see if maybe they were conflicting. However, even with a single view rendering, the header still wouldn't show up until I refresh the page.

Here is what I'm doing in my BrowseHeader view:

```
var browseHeader = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    template: function() {
        dust.render('dust/browseHeader','', function(error, output) {
            $('#wrapper').append(output);
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        this.template();
    },
    el: '#wrapper',
    events: {
        'click .academy_filter' : "click_filter"
    },
    click_filter: function(event) {
        target = event.target;
        $('.academy_filter').removeClass('active');
        $(target).addClass('active');
        EventBus.trigger('header:click_filter', target);
    }
});
```

When I console.log the output, it does display the html for the output despite it not being shown on the page. So I know my dust template is working. When I simplify my BrowseHeader render function to just $('#wrapper').append("this"); I still experience the same issue.

Any ideas?

**Update:** Apparently it has something to do with browser and pushState because when I changed my router to the following, it worked fine.

Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

Comment: Is `#wrapper` in the DOM when you expect it to be?

Comment: Are you certain? This has all the hallmarks of a timing problem.

Comment: When and where is the view created? Personally, I've stopped calling `render` in the `initialize` function because it causes too many strange issues. In my opinion, it's better to render manually, if if you do so immediately after creating the view.

Comment: I tried moving the render function out of the initialize function and it still does the same thing. The view is being created in the route.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing wrong with your view. This is most likely a timing issue. Your view is probably being initialized (and therefore rendered) before `#wrapper` exists in the DOM. My guess is that if you try the following, the output will be `0`:

```
dust.render('dust/browseHeader','', function(error, output) {
  console.log($('#wrapper').length);
  $('#wrapper').append(output);
});
```

Make sure the view is being created after the DOM has finished loading, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var header = new browseHeader();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, when I console.log what you wrote, it says 1 even though it's not showing up.